# Using the web service (Website Payment Pro) for payment. Will apple approve this?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, paypal

I've made an iPhone application which replicates the web site. We're using Website Payment Pro on the server side for the payment. I'm sending the credit card details from the iPhone application using a web service for the payment. And getting the response which shown to the user.

Im concern whether apple will approve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will probably be denied placement in the appstore if you do this.

If you check out the approval guidlines http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

You can find these points:

```
Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected
```

So technically it isn't allowed.  However ff you really want to do it redirect users from the app to a mobile website (in safari not in app) that handles the payement. This way it is not in app and you at least don't violate the 2nd point.

However this will still breach the first point so YMMV

Comment: This is not necessarily right as it does not apply to consumer goods.

Comment: I agree Rog, if the OP is selling physical products, e.g. clothes then he is fine using Website Payment Pro.

Comment: Right, if you sell real-life products or similar you will be fine. In App Purchase is only required of you sell additional content of your app. Guess no one could do a mobile shopping app if it wasn't so.

Answer (score 1):

what are you selling? this determines whether or not you can use an alternative payment method.

If you are selling physical goods you will be fine. If you are selling features/functionality for use in-app then you have to use Apple' in-app payment program.

Answer (score 0):

I emailed Apple regarding this question from iTunes Contact us section. I got the following response:

> Hello XXXX,
>
> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Support regarding the iOS Developer
>   Program.
>
> I understand that you have a question about an App you are developing.  I
>   also understand you are requesting to verify that your App will not be
>   rejected by the app review team.  You will be able to get your answer by
>   reviewing the Program License Agreement and the App Review Guidelines.  If
>   you App conforms to those documents then you will need to submit your App
>   for review and that team will make sure your App conforms to those
>   documents.
>
> Developers should be testing and developing their apps in line with the iOS
>   Developer Program License Agreement and the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Should you have any questions or concerns, we request that you review the
>   iOS Developer Program License Agreement details with your own legal counsel.
>   You may view a copy of the agreement via the Member Center - Your Account
>   area:
>
> http://developer.apple.com/membercenter
>
> Additionally, the App Store Review Guidelines can be found on our website:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
>
> Thank you for your participation in our programs. Please let me know if you
>   have any questions regarding this information or need further assistance.

Comment: Typical lawyer style, useless response.